# If $2$ is subtracted from each root,the results are reciprocals of the original roots.Find the value of $b^2+c^2+bc.$

Tags: quadratics

The equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ has distinct roots .If $2$ is subtracted from each root,the results are reciprocals of the original roots.Find the value of $b^2+c^2+bc.$

---

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$.
According to the question,
$\alpha-2=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\beta-2=\frac{1}{\beta}$
$\alpha^2-2\alpha-1=0$ and $\beta^2-2\beta-1=0$
Adding the two equations,
$\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha-2\beta-2=0$
$(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta-2\alpha-2\beta-2=0$
$(-b)^2-2c-2(-b)-2=0$
$b^2+2b-2c-2=0$
But i am not able to find $b^2+c^2+bc=0.$What should i do now?I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint...$\alpha^2-2\alpha-1=0\Rightarrow b=-2, c=-1$

Answer (score 0):

So from equation we get quadratic which is $x^2-2x-1$ so roots if this are $1+\sqrt{2},1-\sqrt{2}$ so sum of roots is $-b/1=2,$ and product is $c/1=-1$ so $b^2+c^2+bc=4+1-2=3$ hope its clear.